How to properly set Icon and license file in vsixManifest file?
I've just published my first visual studio extension and having some problems with setting the Icon and license file to the source.extension.vsixmanifest file.
I've tried googling and getting help from AI tools such as ChatGPT and Claude.Ai but nothing I do seems to help.
I've created the project using the Code refactoring (.Net standard) template, which generates two projects - one for the code and one for the vsix, and manually changed just a few things in the vsixManifest file. Here's the current file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="AutoEntityGenerator..3633938B-4D62-4E7A-92C3-BCBBD5DEEFE6"
              Version="1.0.0"
              Language="en-US"
              Publisher="Zohar Peled"/>
    <DisplayName>AutoEntityGenerator</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">Automatically generates DTO and mapping classes based on your domain entities.</Description>
    <Icon>AutoEntityCreator.png</Icon>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[16.0,17.0)">
      <ProductArchitecture>x86</ProductArchitecture>
    </InstallationTarget>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[17.0,)">
      <ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>
    </InstallationTarget>
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5,)" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="AutoEntityGenerator" Path="|AutoEntityGenerator|"/>
  </Assets>
  <Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices" Version="[15.0,)" DisplayName="Roslyn Language Services" />
  </Prerequisites>
</PackageManifest>

When I attempt to add the <License> tag, I get the following warning:

The element 'Metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011' has invalid child element 'License' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011'. List of possible elements expected: 'PreviewImage, Tags, Preview, Version' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011' as well as any element in namespace '##other'.

I've tried updating the Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools package (currently installed 17.10.2185, tried updating to the latest available version which is 17.11.414) but gut an error from nuget:

Unable to find package Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK.Analyzers with version (>= 17.7.41)

Found 28 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 17.7.32 ]


As for the Icon - I've double checked, the icon file appears in the bin/release directory with the correct name, it's a valid png file bot for some reason I can't get it to show in the visual studio's extensions menu's installed tab.

Did you add the <License> tag in VSIX Manifest Designer?
If the file does not contain valid XML, the manifest designer won't open. Please check whether you can open the designer after adding <License>.

Unable to find package Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK.Analyzers with version (>= 17.7.41)

I am able to reproduce the same error when i update package Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools to 17.11.414.
When i checked the Dependencies of the package from nuget websites, it notes that Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools depends on Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK.Analyzers (>= 17.7.41). However the latest version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK.Analyzers is 17.7.32. This may cause the NU1102 error: unable to find packageg xxx.


I suggest you can click report package on nuget org.
However based on my test, when i build the VSIX project, the build seems ignores the nuget package error and displays success.

When i checked the "bin/release" folder, the icon file and license file appear there.
After packaging the extension, go to the Tools menu and click Extensions and Updates. The TestPublish extension appears in the center pane with icon.

Hope it can help you.
Update by Zohar:
After our conversation in the comments, I've added a new project to my  solution using the Empty VSIX Project template, where I could use the vsixManifest designer. Then I've edited the vsixmanifest in this project with the relevant details and removed the project that contained the old vsixManifest.
This solved the problem for me.

Thanks for your answer, the designer indeed will not open for me, however I can't find any problem in the xml itself. I'll try to generate a manifest with a new project using the designer and copy its content to my current project. Hope that will fix the issue.

Well, that still didn't help. When I create a new project using the Code refactoring (.Net standard) template, the vsixmanifest file only opens as an xml, not in the designer. However, when I create a new project using the Empty VSIX project template, it does open the designer. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

I am able to reproduce the same issue on my side. From looking at the .csproj file, one is an SDK project, the other is a .net framework project. As Tina said, " it’s a known issue that the VSIX Manifest designer doesn’t work with SDK style projects". This may be the reason why the vsixmanifest file behaves differently.

Copy the vsixmanifest  file in the Code refactoring project to the file vsixmanifest  in the Empty VSIX project, and then open it with designer to verify whether there is a  invalid XML. Can you open it with designer?

I'll give it a try and let you know. Meanwhile I've created a POC going the other way around - created a new solution with 3 projects - two from the .net standard template and one from the empty vsix template, and then simply added the code project as a mef asset to the empty vsix project and removed the one that came with the template. This seems to be working as the code is running and I can use the designer, but I would like to try your suggested solution as well.

Well, it does work on the POC - same manifest file opens in one project just as an xml and in the other in the designer - so thank you very much for that! Now I've tried adding the icon and license on the POC and it seems to be working fine. Thanks for your help! BTW, if you'll allow me, I'll edit your answer to include my solution and accept it

Glad to hear that you have found the solution. Please feel free to modify the answer to make it complete.
